# How to reverse each item in the nested list?

Tags: python, list, reverse

*Lists are used to store multiple items in a single variable.
Lists are created using square brackets.*

**I want to reverse each item in the list of a list.**

I tried **reversed** and **[::1]** method but it did not gave me desired output.

`Here is my list`
**list1 = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 6, 7, [8, 9, 10]]**

I tried **print(list1[::-1])** and **reversed(list1)** and got this output

**output: [[8, 9, 10], 7, 6, [4, 5, 6], 3, 2, 1]**

How could I get this output?

`output: [[10, 9, 8], 7, 6, [6, 5, 4], 3, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
list1 = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 6, 7, [8, 9, 10]]
list1.reverse()
for sub_list in list1:
  if type(sub_list) is list:
        sub_list.reverse()
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive function.

```py
def revall(l):
    return [revall(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in l[::-1]]
print(revall([1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 6, 7, [8, 9, 10]]))
```